# what's the difference between object * x and object& x in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between pointer variable and reference variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

suppose I'm trying to pass a reference to object x to a c++ function...

what's the difference between

```
pass(Object * x){


}
```

and

```
pass(Object& x){

}
```

and how would you access the actual object itself when the pointer/reference is declared using the different methods...

for instance if I have Object * x, how would I actually access the actual object that is referenced by x

same with Object& x

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first is a pass by pointer. The second is a pass by reference.

As for usage, a pointer must be "dereferenced" before it can be used. That is done with the `*` and `->` operators:

```
void do_something(Object * x)
{
    Object & ref = *x; // * returns a reference
    ref.method();
    x->method(); // same as (*x).method()
}
```

References have no such restriction:

```
void do_something(Object & x)
{
    x.method();
}
```

However, references can only point to a single object for their whole lifetime, while pointers can change target and (as John mentionned below) point to "nothing" (that is, `NULL`, `0` or, in C++0x, `nullptr`). There is no such thing as a `NULL` reference in C++.

Since references are easier to use and less error-prone, prefer them unless you know what you're doing (pointers are a pretty tough subject).

Comment: ...which for one thing means the first could be NULL (no object) whereas the second cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference means the **caller** should guarantee that the referred object is valid. Pass by pointer **usually** requires the **function** to check whether the pointer is NULL.

Pass by reference also means the **function** don't care about the lifecycle of the object. Pass by pointer **may** require the **function** to destruct the object.

So, apparently, pass by reference has clear semantics, less possibility, less error-prone.